# Globally set default 'nullable=false' for @Column definition

Tags: java, jpa, orm, annotations

From [`@Column`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#nullable%28%29) annotation documentation i verified `nullable` attribute has `true` as default value.

In my entities definitions I'd like to set columns **non-nullable** as default behavior, but I don't want to set this for every single column.

Is there a way to **globally** change default value for `nullable` attribute (and eventually others)?

Answer (score 1):

JPA takes the nullable property from the tables on your database if the columns on your table were `notnull` then your entity attributes would be `@NotNull` too. You could do the changes on your database and recreate the entities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a way to override JPA default settings, but you could use EntityListeners to perform some @PrePersist validations and check that an object fields (non transient ones) are not null by reflection.

Having said that, I believe that this makes the entity definition less clear and would rather stick to the more declarative technique using (nullable="false").